# How do I export a world from Minecraft win 10?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, windows

How do I export my world from Minecraft windows 10 edition? I bought my version of Minecraft from the Microsoft store and I don’t know how to export my worlds. I looked through my files and all I could find was Minecraft java.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a world's file by going into the Edit World screen of the world you want to export, and click the button at the bottom of the  page on the "Game" tab. You can also click "Delete World" (this action is permanent) or click "Copy World" to duplicate the world.

[image]
Clicking the Export World button will open a Save As dialogue where you can save an outputted `.mcworld` file to a folder on your computer. You can then import it back into Minecraft by clicking the button next to the "Create New" button.

You can then reimport it into Minecraft by clicking this button:
[image: Second Button]
If you still are really curious as to where world files are actually stored, you can find them at this path on MCBE Win10:

```
C:\Users\ExpertCoder14\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds
```

Answer (score 1):

Click the pencil icon by your world then scroll to the bottom and press "Export World"